# Protobuf-net: jagged arrays with wrapper

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

I know that protobuf-net doesn't support a jagged array and a wrapper is a workaround. I've tried to test it, serialization works fine, but deserialization does nothing, i.e. no error, after deserialization the objects are empty.

```
[ProtoContract(ImplicitFields = ImplicitFields.AllPublic)]
public class Source
{
    public Source()
    {
        List = new List<Dictionary<string, Item>>();
    }

    [ProtoIgnore]
    public List<Dictionary<string, Item>> List { get; set; }

    public List<DictionaryWrapper<string, Item>> ListProto
    {
        get
        {
            return List.ConvertAll(x => new DictionaryWrapper<string, Item>(x));
        }
        set
        {
            List = value.ConvertAll(x => x.Dictionary);
        }
    }
}

[ProtoContract(ImplicitFields = ImplicitFields.AllPublic)]
public class Item
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

[ProtoContract(ImplicitFields = ImplicitFields.AllPublic)]
public sealed class DictionaryWrapper<TKey, TValue>
{
    public DictionaryWrapper()
    {
    }

    public DictionaryWrapper(Dictionary<TKey, TValue> value)
    {
        Dictionary = value;
    }

    public Dictionary<TKey, TValue> Dictionary { get; set; }
}
```

serialization method

```
    public void Test()
    {
        byte[] data = null;
        try
        {
            var source = new Source();

            for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                source.List.Add(new Dictionary<string, Item> {{i.ToString(), new Item {Value = i.ToString()}}});
            }

            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                Serializer.Serialize(stream, source);
                data = stream.ToArray();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }

        Source result;
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(data))
        {
             result = Serializer.Deserialize<Source>(stream);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(result.List.Count);
    }
```

UPDATE: I've found a workaround. So this fixes the deserialization, still, don't know why `ListProto set` was not called.

```
    [ProtoBeforeSerialization]
    public void ProtoBeforeSerialization()
    {
        List1Proto = List1.ConvertAll(x => new DictionaryWrapper<string, Item>(x));
    }

    [ProtoAfterDeserialization]
    public void ProtoAfterDeserialization()
    {
        List1 = List1Proto.ConvertAll(x => x.Dictionary);
    }
```